# Heroku Rails app, Bootstrap not loading from Bowerfile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Using Heroku to deploy my Rails application for some testing. Application deploys fine, however the Bootstrap is not loaded from the Bowerfile. To clarify, I have a Bowerfile in the main directory that contains `asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'`(when application is running locally, everything works as expected). I also have the `'bower-rails'` gem installed, as well as the required line in the application.css file `require 'bootstrap-sass-official'`. I also have the `rake assets:precompile` running at the time of deployment with no issues. I have also tried running `heroku rake bower:install` which tells me to install Bower via npm, which I already have installed.

I have looked for solutions, but no luck. Help?

Comment: I don't know whether you've already seen this:Relative asset paths

Some bower components (eg. Bootstrap) have relative urls in the CSS files for imports, images, etc. Rails prefers using helper methods for linking to assets within CSS. Relative paths can cause issues when assets are precompiled for production.

Comment: @TomConnolly thanks, I will look into this.